# Images are not showing up in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I have got a theme downloaded from http://template-help.com. I have followed the instruction manual provided by them to install the theme and demo site along with that. In localhost its all working smoothly, but when i uploaded it to the server thats when the images started playing up. Could see the images in there. i can very well see the files inside the directory where it is trying to find the images using firebug. I am pasting the image tag for example where the image is coming from.. its all perfect but still image is not showing up.

```
<img src="http://myoxygenmobile.co.uk/sites/default/files/slide1_0.jpg" width="463" height="383" alt=""/>
```

I have also attached the screen shot of it. Any help please?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the permissions of the folder **sites/default/files** make sure it's set to **777** (writable for every one).

Hope this helps... Muhammad.